# Scheme, checking not equal int?

Tags: scheme

How can I check if 3 natural numbers are not equal (at all), 2 of the 3 are equals or all of them are equal?

The last one makes perfect sense but I am confused because of the first two. How do I check whether 2 of 3 are equal?

I had a function `(define-struct (func1 num1))`

I used `not (= (struct-num1) (struct-num2) (struct-num3))`

But it returns true if 2 or 3 are equal.

Comment: The straightforward way to check if three numbers are all different (e.g. 3 6 4) is to check that each pair is different: `(a != b) and (a != c) and (b != c)`. Checking that all three are equal (e.g. 4 4 4) you can do. If both checks return false, then exactly two must be equal (e.g. 3 6 3).

Comment: @tom you should write your comment as answer.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: Good point, done.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way to check if three numbers are all different (e.g. 3 6 4) is to check that each pair is different:

```
(and (not (= a b)) (not (= a c)) (not (= b c)))
```

Checking that all three are equal (e.g. 4 4 4) you can do already.

If both checks return false, then exactly two must be equal (e.g. 3 6 3).